# How could I add these tables that reference each other

Tags: sql-server

How can I add this two table together at the same time, because otherwise, it won't let me at all

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
 StudentID      Int             NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
FullName        VarChar(100)                NOT NULL,
GraduationYear  Int             NOT NULL,
Balance          INT                NOT NULL,
Degree          Varchar(100)        NOT NULL,
TransactionID       Int                 NULL,
ReturnID        Int             Null,
Contact     Int             NOT NULL,       
Email           Varchar(60)     NOT NULL,
Street          Varchar(60)     NOT NULL,
Town            Varchar(60)     NOT NULL,
Zip         Int             NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Student_PK   PRIMARY KEY(StudentID),
CONSTRAINT Student_Transactions_FK  FOREIGN KEY(TransactionID)
    REFERENCES Transactions(TransactionID),
CONSTRAINT Student_BookReturn_FK    FOREIGN KEY(ReturnID)
    REFERENCES BookReturn(ReturnID)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions
(
TransactionID           Int             NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
BookId              Int             NOT NULL,
DueDate             DateTime        NOT NULL,
DateTransaction     DateTime        NOT NULL,
TransactionStatus       Varchar(100)    NULL,
StudentID           INT             NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Transactions_PK  PRIMARY KEY(TransactionID),
CONSTRAINT Transactions_BookInformation_FK  FOREIGN KEY(BookID)
    REFERENCES BookInformation(BookID),
 CONSTRAINT Transactions_Student_FK FOREIGN KEY(StudentID)
    REFERENCES Student(StudentID)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION

);
```

Comment: It seems the problem is not the code, but the normalization. `TransactionID` and `ReturnID` columns souldn't be on the student table.

Comment: I'm guessing your schema design is "backwards". Surely you can expect a student to have multiple transactions? The same thought applies to ReturnID. The column Contact has a smell to it as well. I suggest you spend some serious thought about your datatype choices and your schema design. E.g., GraduationYear is a 4 digit number that has a very small valid range - not int.

Comment: But the general approach to avoid this type of dependency error is to create all tables with primary key constraints first. Then you alter those tables by adding the foreign keys.

Comment: As others have pointed out, your design being fundamentally flawed is a bigger issue, as circular Foreign Key references are generally not a recommended implementation and is only possible in your case because one of the Foreign Keys (on `Student.TransactionId`) is nullable. Also what database system is this for (please update your tags appropriately) Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `CREATE TABLE` without constraints
2. Run `ALTER TABLE` to add constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular constraint. Even if you were able to trick SQL Server into letting you create both tables with the constraints you want to add, you'll never be able to insert data into either of them.

Try removing the TransactionID and ReturnID columns from the Students table all together, along with the corresponding constraints. You don’t need to track those values at the Student level. Those are all transaction details, to which you’ll have a one to many relationship between student and the number of transactions they preform.